# URL injection problem

Tags: security, ce-1.9.1.1

someone has injected some weird URLs to my Magento store which now redirect to the third website. Google thinks, of course, that my page is hacked and it shows that on its search engine. I want to avoid that at every cost.

I have gone through some major directories to check for permissions and everything looks okay.

What should I do, where else might the backdoor be? Is there any plugin to help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: What Magento version you are using?

Comment: I am on Magento Community 1.9.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the custom scripts in *System > Configuration > Web* and see if there are any weird java script snippets.

I am positive that's where the problem will be. Ensure you have the latest SUPEE patches installed also.

Comment: Hm, I have found the js folder but nothing that would be strange. There is recent upload of "fusty-flow.js", which I can see is HTML5 upload js file. Should not be malicious?

Comment: Hi, you're not looking for a folder you're looking in the admin file in system configuration then click web under 3 of those sections there are areas for JS code to be inserted